# Needs to identify if input is greater than 90 and print those values and identify if the input is less than 60 and print those values

Tags: java, arrays

The program needs to ask the user how many courses it took which is the number of elements in the array. Then it needs to identify which grades are below 65 and print those and then identify which grades are above 90 and print those. Right now, the output just prints 0,1,2,3,4,5 after asking the user for how many courses they took and their grade in each of the course.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class StudentApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Number = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many courses did you take during the school year: ");
        int x= Number.nextInt();

        int grades[] = new int[x];

        for (int courses =1; courses<=x; courses++) {
            System.out.print("Enter your grade for that course: ");
            Number.nextInt();
            int y = Number.nextInt();
        }

        for (int counter = 0; counter < grades.length; counter++) {
            if (counter < 65) {
                System.out.print(counter);
            }

            if (counter >90) {
                System.out.print("\n"+counter);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: That's not surprising, considering you're checking and printing `counter`. And you never even store the grade inputs.

Comment: What would be the fix @shmosel

Comment: You probably want to write them to your array.

Comment: You created the `grades` array, but you're not using it, so why did you create it? (Re)read your Java learning material for how to use arrays. StackOverflow is not a teaching site for teaching you the very basics of the Java language. You have to do the work of studying yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what u want?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many courses did you take during the school year? : ");
    int takeCoursesNum = sc.nextInt();

    int grades[] = new int[takeCoursesNum]; // array number start "0" ~ ex) { [0], [1], [2] }

    for (int i = 0; i < takeCoursesNum; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter your grade for that course : ");
        int grade = sc.nextInt();
        grades[i] = grade;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < takeCoursesNum; i++) {
        if (grades[i] < 65) {
            System.out.println("below 65 : " + i);// System.out.println : auto change line. no need \n.
        }

        if (grades[i] > 90) {
            System.out.println("above 90 : " + i);
        }
    }
```

I hope it is. Happy Codinging :)

Comment: For this code, say if there are two grades between 90, it will print "above 90" twice when displaying the two grades. However, I want it to print Above 90: grade 1, grade 2 @Super Shark